# decide $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{1} \frac{dx}{1+n^4x^4}$ convergance

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{1} \frac{dx}{1+n^4x^4}$

how can one decide convergence / divergence of such sum ? i have seen context where they turn the integral and the sum why is it allowed ?

> tried to substitute its tough integral to solve

$t = nx$

$dt = n~dx$

$\int_0^{1} \frac{dx}{1+n^4x^4} = \frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n} \frac{dt}{1+t^4}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^{1} \frac{dx}{1+n^4x^4}&=&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{n} \frac{du}{1+u^4}\\&\ge&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+u^4}du\\&\ge&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{1+u^2}du=\frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Really good solution did you use the fact that $ 0\leq u \leq 1 $ and so the function is greater in the second line ? so the integral is greater

Comment: Sure I did :) I hope this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with what you have done $ \int_0^{n} \frac 1 {1+t^{4}}dt$ tends to a finite positive limit as $n \to \infty$. Hence this the given sum is $\geq \delta \sum \frac 1 n$ for some $\delta >0$ which makes the series divergent. In fact $ \int_0^{n} \frac 1 {1+t^{4}}dt \geq \int_0^{1} \frac 1 2 dt =\frac 1 2$.

Comment: thank you sir could you explain the last inequality i cant mark that as a solution too it wont let me

Comment: On $(0,1)$ we have $1+t^{4} <1+1=2$ so $\frac 1 {1+t^{4}} >\frac 1 2$.

Comment: @Mather You can only accept one answer.

Comment: oh nice fast and clear